# Get Currency Data

Tags: java

I am currently developing a sort of toolbox program with different conversions (miles to kilometers, Celsius to Fahrenheit, etc) and would like to create a class which converts Pounds (GBP) to Dollars (USD).

The problem I'm having is that, as you know, currency conversion rates are constantly changing. What I want to know is: is there a way to get conversion rate data from a website or database so that it is always up to date and what is the best way to do it?

Comment: what did you try so far? please post relevant code

Answer (score -2):

http://fixer.io/
For example can convert any currency via API.